# Data Scientists | Sectors , Departments and Profiles

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, bigdata, data

I'm searching a lot about what people call Data Scientist. From my brief search, I've came with the conclusion that Data Scientists' are probably what you may call the future evolution of a Business Intelligence Professional, by focusing important topics such has machine learning, big data, etc.

In this search It's being difficult to define what may be the most important sectors, departments (inside companies) and main profiles to this subject.

Can someone help me on understanding what is happening to the business world around this subject?

Summary:

- Most important sectors? (for example, is it the retail and bank sector? There are more?)
- Most important departments? (are the majority of Data Scientists working on IT departments? Risk departments? Marketing? I have no idea.)
- Most important topics about the profile of a Data Scientist (what are the imperative skills to have?)